# Error message not being sent to login page

Tags: php, mysql

**Sorry for my bad english.**

I'm trying to make a login form and I've run into a pickle. I'm trying to make an error message with the variable `$error` return on the main site. It doesn't seem to work like this as it stays on the MySQL directory. I have setup my 2 `*.php` files in the same directory which one uses `html5` and the other uses `php5`. I was wondering if I could have some assistance.

**index.php**

```
<div class="margin">
      <h1 class="hc">Login</h1>
        <center><form action="login.php" method="POST" name="registration" class="formcontainer">
          <label for="user">Username</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" maxlength="254"></input>
          <br/><br/>
          <label for="user">Password</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" maxlength="254"></input>
          <br/><br/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Login <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></button>
        </form>
        <br/><br/>
      <span class="content"><?php echo $error; ?></span></center>
        <br><br>
    </div>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php


session_start();
$error = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $server = "localhost";
  $id = "xxxx";
  $pw = "xxxx";
  $dbName = "xxxx";

  $link = mysql_connect($server, $id, $pw);

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $db = mysql_select_db($dbName, $link);

  $login_request = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

  $login_check = mysql_num_rows($login_request);


if ($login_check == 1) {
  $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
  header("Location: /dev/profile/");
} elseif($login_check == 0) {
  $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the authentication is invalid , redirect back to login form and set a `$_GET` that actually works as a flag, if in your authentication form the `$_GET` is set then print the error msg.

**login.php**

```
if ($login_check == 1) {
  $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
  header("Location: /dev/profile/");
} elseif($login_check == 0) {
  $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
  header("Location:" .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?logerror=".$error);
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <span class="content">
<?php if (isset($_GET['logerror'])) {
 echo $_GET['logerror']; } ?>
</span></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your HTML in php and include second one on top of it. There is no chance, that two files will magically connect, so merge them

```
<?php include("login.php") ?>
<div class="margin">
      <h1 class="hc">Login</h1>
        <center><form action="index.php" method="POST" name="registration" class="formcontainer">
          <label for="user">Username</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" maxlength="254"></input>
          <br/><br/>
          <label for="user">Password</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" maxlength="254"></input>
          <br/><br/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Login <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></button>
        </form>
        <br/><br/>
      <span class="content"><?php echo $error; ?></span></center>
        <br><br>
    </div>
```